# Unable to connect to CNCYDEV on port 5252. No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: hyper-v, networking

I have a server that uses K2 (www.k2.com), SQL Server, Sharepoint 2010 and many other products. When using K2, I am experiencing the error stated in the title of this question. I contacted K2 Support and had several screenshares with their team over the course of two months. At the end, we tried everything, and acknowledged that **it wasn't an issue on their side**. I'm very confident that this is some sort of network issue, since I already checked multiple SQL resources and verified that the SQL Config Manager is properly configured.

A little background, I'm getting the error when I actually start a K2 workflow. 5252 is the port used by the K2 Workflow Server, and we verified that this is configured correctly in the K2 environment. CNCYDEV is the host name of the machine. I'm interacting with this server through RDP. The server itself is a Hyper-V server running on a laptop near my desk. This issue is **intermittent**; sometimes the error will be thrown on the first try, other times I will be able to start the workflow several times before the error is thrown. Note that **once the error is thrown, it will continue to be thrown every single time** until some time has passed (usually 15-30 minutes).

Here are some of the things I have tried:

- With both the firewall on the Hyper-V server and the firewall on the owning laptop OFF, I still encounter this issue.
- No entries related to this error show in the Event Viewer.
- Tried restarting the K2 service in services.msc
- Reviewed the K2 logs with the support staff, they found nothing amiss.
- Ran netstat and found that something was listening on 0.0.0.0:5252, the process ID in the output was the K2 service, which was running.
- Ran a SQL profiler trace, but nothing shows up.
- Re-configured SQL Server Configuration Manager with support staff, compared values with theirs, and restarted the SQL server and browser.
- Did everything in this post with no issues (except #9 which I don't know how to test): http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2007/07/19/tcp-provider-no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-refused-it.aspx
- Fiddler didn't show an error or message related to the error stated above, but Wireshark generated some red-colored lines EXACTLY at the time the error is thrown - WS log below for analysis.

Wireshark Log: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qqagfuhavxz7dqi/WS_Log.pcap?dl=0

I found the top answer of [this SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972600/no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-refused-it) very interesting as it seems to be my issue - but how do I clear out a full backlog? What is a server backlog anyway, I am not finding much helpful information on this on the internet?

Thanks, I appreciate any help you can give.

P.S. I apologize if the tags aren't accurate, it's a generic issue to me and I'm new to this SE site, please recommend some tags if they could help the question.

Comment: Anyone? *crickets* I need to stop making TL;DR posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not a direct answer or solution to my problem, a quick and easy fix was to just kill the VHD and restore the original version, which was on our network drive. The original doesn't have the problem, so I am good to go.